# How to test CPU hot plug on Windows?

Tags: linux, powershell, cpu-usage, window, embedded

I tried CPU hot plug testing with Linux using the command lines :

Set online/offline individual core or group cores:

> echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
>
> echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online

Run stress-ng after set online/offline
In my point of view, Windows doesn't support PowerShell to enable/disable cores and we just test CPU hot plug via VM (Virtual machines). I hope someone who uses to test this function on Windows without using VM can come up with other solutions. Thanks so much!

Comment: Windows seems to support hot plug CPUs, but the hardware will need to support it too. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried CPU hotplug on Windows with VM (Virtual Machine), but I need another solution, my best-expected solution that can use PowerShell to set online/offline core or group cores same Linux. Or some Windows tools to do that.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. I still don't know if you're talking about virtual or physical, if you're asking about a way to script preparing the machine for disabling a CPU so that I can be removed, or what. Please edit your question and make it more clear. If your question is about Windows, cut the stuff about Linux: that had nothing to do with the question and so shouldn't be there.